# Let us have some TeX-mas fun [completed]

Tags: discussion, fun, ducks

I hope we all know that Christmas is fast approaching. This indeed means that

> **\begin{holidays} with a hope that it never ends \ldots but \ldots \end{holidays}.**

So, before we start celebrating the new-year, christmas and our holidays, I think we can have a contest where one should design an `avatar-with-a-sweater`.

Of course, this sweater can be ugly/pretty. And, it's upto the participants' choice.

> ***Rules:***
>
> [1] You can have any number of designs.
>
> [2] You must explicitly specify under which category you want your avatar to be evaluated. Those include:
>
> ```
>    a. Beautiful avatar with an ugly sweater.
>
>    b. Beautiful avatar with a pretty sweater.
>
>    c. Both **a and b** ;)
> ```
>
> [3] Winner is chosen based on the number of up-votes!!
>
> [4] The competition ends on ***31-12-2018 23:59:59***

There can be two-winners:

> 1. Beautiful avatar with a pretty sweater.
> 2. Beautiful avatar with an ugly sweater.

Of course, our own ***ducklings*** are more than welcome!!

Let the `TeX-mas` begin :D

> Disclaimer: The `ducks` tag is just here because I like ***DUCKS***.

**UPDATE 1:**

> Results of this event is available as an accepted answer.

Comment: And ducks like you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, now I know it for sure :D

Comment: I don't think killer rabbits look good in sweaters :(

Comment: @Skillmon You can show us :D

Comment: **WHO WON???????**

Comment: @David Carlisle The results are being processed by the council of `ducklings` and it will be announced shortly ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Results TeXmas: 2018**

First of all the `council of ducklings` would like to share their appreciation for all the participants: *Thanks for joining this event and I hope was fun ;)*

After a long discussion -- in the midst of new year party -- by the `council of ducklings` over the results of this competition, it has been finalisied that

> **David Carlisle** is the sole winner of the event under the category for `beautiful avatar with a pretty sweater`. **Skillmon** dont forget to get him a beer!*
>
> **Skillmon** and **CarLaTeX** will share the winner award of the event under the category for `beautiful avatar with an ugly sweater`.

On behalf of the council, I would again like to thank all the winners and participants for their participation in this `TeXmas: 2018` and making this as a successful event (I think).

I hope you all had fun, and see you all in the next edition!

Have a very great new year ahead!!

Comment: Thanks for putting on a great event! I look forward to the next one. :)

Comment: @Ulysses you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 19):

clearly this entry is in category b,

```
 --- see avatar here ----------------------------------------------
                                                                  |
                                                                  |
                                                                  V
```

Comment: Wow! I think otherwise :D

Comment: If you win this thing I'll buy you a beer!

Answer (score 17):

Without ducks. ;-)

```
\documentclass[border={1cm 3.14mm 1cm 3.14mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings} % https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \marmot[whiskers,teeth,3D,shadow]
 \fill[top color=blue!70,bottom color=blue,shading angle=-30] 
 (-0.56,1.35) to[out=-10,in=190] (0.56,1.35) 
 to[out=-80,in=85] (0.58,0.6) to[out=-175,in=-5] (-0.58,0.6) 
  to[out=95,in=-100] cycle;
 \shade[ball color=brown!50!black,rotate around={70:(0.385,0.93)}] (0.385,0.93) ellipse (0.24 and 0.13);
 \shade[ball color=brown!50!black,rotate around={-70:(-0.385,0.93)}] (-0.385,0.93) ellipse (0.24 and 0.13);
 \penguin[yshift=0.7cm,scale=0.25]  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [no ducks doesn't means it's not pretty;)] could you state your preference `a\b\c`

Comment: @Raaja It is b since the penguin does not have a sweater. ;-)

Comment: thanks for the explicit clarification ;)

Comment: I wish `tikzlings` had a toucan, a hummingbird, or a parrot. Little pearl of a package.

Comment: You are a danger for David's bear!

Comment: @marmot Argg, stupid typo! Sorry!  `/s/bear/beer`

Comment: @samcarter [Related](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48087463#48087463) ;-)

Comment: @marmot Oh, beer seems to be THE topic of the day :)

Answer (score 14):

This is my entry for Category B (pretty sweaters). It features my avatar (a Ulysses butterfly) on a sweater. If it displays right, the wings should flap intermittently. I coded this image using just the `tikz` and `animate` packages, and using [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Papilio_ulysses_ambiguus_Rothschild%2C_1895.JPG) as a reference for the butterfly.

Just for fun, I gave myself the personal challenge of creating this using only the default features of these packages, i.e. no pre-made images, no additional libraries, no more than the basic colours, and no significant contributions from other packages (I've got `times` and `geometry` in there as well, just for a nicer font and some margin controls, but that's it). I had a lot of fun doing this and really expanded my knowledge of `tikz`, which I'm really pleased about.

Larger version of the butterfly can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkjcP.gif).

[image: Butterfly sweater by Ulysses]

For anyone who wants to know how I did this, below is my complete code. Please note that you'll need Adobe Acrobat Reader to view the resulting animated pdf (which I highly recommend checking out as the above gif just does not do it justice). Also be aware that I'm still quite the newbie when it comes to LaTeX and `tikz` so there may be a few quirks. Any hints and tips would be much appreciated. :)

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{article}
% All design and code created by Ulysses. Please credit me if you use a significant portion of this anywhere.

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{times}

\newcommand{\halfwing}[1]{
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=#1]
    % Lower Wing
    \filldraw[fill=black!90!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.2) -- (0,1.4) -- (-2,1.4) .. controls (-4,0.8) .. (-4.3,0.2) .. controls (-4.48,0.08) .. (-4.5,-0.15) .. controls (-4.9,-0.5) and (-4.9,-0.7) .. (-4.7,-0.9) .. controls (-4.7,-1) .. (-4.6,-1.1) .. controls (-4.9,-1.8) .. (-4.2,-2) -- (-4,-2.4) .. controls (-4.1,-3) .. (-3.6,-3.1) -- (-3.25,-3.7) .. controls (-3.5,-4.5) .. (-4.1,-5.4) .. controls (-4.2,-5.9) and (-3.6,-5.9) .. (-3.5,-5.4) .. controls (-3.55,-5.1) and (-3.4,-4.8) .. (-3,-4.1) -- (-2.6,-4.1) .. controls (-2.35,-4.35) .. (-2,-4.2) .. controls (-1.75,-4.6) and (-1.25,-4.6) .. (-1.25,-3.90) .. controls (-0.9,-4) .. (-0.6,-2.8) -- (-0.3,-1) -- (0,0.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!45!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black,rounded corners=1mm] (-0.8,-3) .. controls (-0.5,-2) .. (-0.30,-0.95){[rounded corners=0mm] .. controls (-0.15,-0.3) .. (-0.05,0.45) -- (-0.05,0.7)} -- (-0.7,0.4) .. controls (-0.9,-2) .. (-0.8,-3);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!60!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-1.1,-2.9) .. controls (-1.4,2) and (0.5,2) .. (-1.1,-2.9);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!70!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-1.6,-2.8) .. controls (-0.9,3.7) and (0,-0.1) .. (-1.6,-2.8);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!70!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.1,-2.6) .. controls (-0.9,3.7) and (-0.3,-0.1) .. (-2.1,-2.6);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.6,-2.2) .. controls (-0.3,3.7) and (-0.3,-0.1) .. (-2.6,-2.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3,-1.7) .. controls (0.1,3.7) and (0.1,-0.1) .. (-3,-1.7);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.4,-1.2) .. controls (0.77,3) and (0.77,-0.2) .. (-3.4,-1.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.6,-0.6) .. controls (0.77,2.2) and (0.77,-0.5) .. (-3.6,-0.6);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!15!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.5,0) .. controls (0.77,1.8) and (0.77,-0.2) .. (-3.5,0);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!10!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.5,0.7) .. controls (0.77,2) and (0.77,0) .. (-2.5,0.7);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!45!cyan!,bottom color=blue!15!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,0.6) -- (-0.05,0.9) .. controls (-4,-0.5) and (-1.5,-2) .. (-0.05,0.6);

    % Upper Wing
    \filldraw[fill=black!90!white!,draw=black,thick] (0,1) -- (0,2.2) [rounded corners=7mm] parabola[bend at end] (-6,6) -- (-5,1) -- (0,1);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!20!cyan!,bottom color=blue!70!cyan!,draw=black] (-4,3.5) .. controls (3,-1) and (-2,4) .. (-4,3.5);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue,draw=black] (-4.1,3) .. controls (3.9,-0.5) and (-2.1,4) .. (-4.1,3);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue!80!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,2.5) .. controls (4,-0.2) and (-2.2,3.5) .. (-4.2,2.5);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue!70!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,1.8) .. controls (4,0.3) and (-2.2,3) .. (-4.2,1.8);
    \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue!60!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,1.2) .. controls (4.05,0.9) and (-2.2,2.4) .. (-4.2,1.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue!60!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,1.85) -- (-0.05,1.80) .. controls (-6.5,6.5) and (-2,5.5) .. (-0.05,1.85);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!10!cyan!,bottom color=blue!50!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,1.8) -- (-0.05,1.4) .. controls (-7.5,5.5) and (-2,5) .. (-0.05,1.8);
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\butterfly}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Guide lines
    %\draw[step=1cm,lightgray,very thin] (-20,-14) grid (20,14);
    %\begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
    %\draw[step=0.2cm,lightgray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (0,2);
    %\draw[step=1cm,cyan,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (0,2);
    %\end{scope}

    % Jumper
    \shadedraw[inner color=white,outer color=blue!30!cyan!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-5,13) arc (180:360:5cm and 3cm) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(10,-17) -- ++(-4,-2) -- ++(-6,10.2) -- ++(0,-17.2) -- ++(-20,0) -- ++(0,17.2) -- ++(-6,-10.2) -- ++(-4,2) -- ++(10,17) -- ++(5,0);
    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!cyan!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-5,13) arc (180:360:5cm and 3cm) -- ++(1,0) arc (180:360:-6cm and 4cm) -- ++(1,0);
    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!cyan!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (20,-4) -- ++(-4,-2) -- ++(-0.5068,0.862) -- ++(4,2) -- ++(0.5068,-0.862);
    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!cyan!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-20,-4) -- ++(4,-2) -- ++(0.5068,0.862) -- ++(-4,2) -- ++(-0.5068,-0.862);

    % Text
    \draw (0,-7) node {\Huge Papilio Ulysses};
    \draw (0,-12.7) node {\large Design and code created by Ulysses.};
    \draw (0,-15.8) node {Reference image used: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Papilio\_ulysses\_ambiguus\_Rothschild\%2C\_1895.JPG};

    % Antenna
    \draw[thick] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
    \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
    \draw[thick] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
    \end{scope}

    % Body
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2.5mm] (0,2.5) -- (0.35,2.5) -- (0.45,1.5) -- (0.45,0) -- (0.25,-2) -- (-0.25,-2) -- (-0.45,0) -- (-0.45,1.5) -- (-0.35,2.5) -- (0,2.5);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,2.24) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.24cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,1.75) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,1.25) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,0.75) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,0.25) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-0.25) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-0.75) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-1.25) ellipse (0.3cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-1.74) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.24cm);

    % Head
    \shadedraw[inner color=black!60!white!,outer color=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2mm] (0,3) -- (0.45,3) -- (0.2,2.3) -- (-0.2,2.3) -- (-0.45,3) -- (0,3);
    \shadedraw[inner color=white!60!black,outer color=black, draw=black,thick] (-0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);
    \shadedraw[inner color=white!60!black,outer color=black, draw=black,thick] (0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);

    % Wings
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
    \halfwing{#1}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.35cm]
    \halfwing{-#1}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,scale=1]{13}
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe[1.5]
    \butterfly{1}
\end{animateinline}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty nice!! Unfortunately, I can only vote once on your vote (weeps), but IMO it should be in `cat-a`.

Comment: Could you clarify why Category A? Not disputing your suggestion - I just don't understand the categories too well.

Comment: According to me, `avatars` are always pretty (`however, ducks are the prettiest ;)`). So the classification is mainly based on whether the sweater is pretty or ugly. And, I think your `sweater` is pretty ;)

Comment: Isn't Category B for the pretty sweaters?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the confusion, time for some coffee I guess :D. You are right!!

Comment: No worries. I'll keep it in category B. :)

Comment: Beautiful ! ! !

Comment: @samcarter now I'm upset that you didn't make that comment on my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not think it was necessary to state the obvious :)

Comment: @Raaja As for `ducks are the prettiest`. OK, maybe, but certainly [not the cutest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449319/121799) ;-)

Comment: @marmot not yet convinced ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess samcarter just didn't want to lose her face.... ;-)

Comment: @marmot Can't let that happen again :)

Comment: Note that species are written in italics with the genus in uppercase and the specific epithet in lowercase:  \textit{Papilio ulysses}

Answer (score 13):

The following sweater features a scene created by @UlrikeFischer from the [Great TikZducks Christmas Extravaganza 2017](https://vimeo.com/246256860)

[image]

I'd like my avatar to enter the contest of pretty sweaters - after all it has ducks, so how can it be ugly? :

Comment: imo it can't be ;)

Comment: @Raaja Correct! :) I'm looking forward to see your avatar in a sweater!

Answer (score 10):

To give @samcarter the credits back, here the shirt/sweater I made with the nice chess figurine she made for me. It naturally enters in b too.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Both categories!

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{marrone}{RGB}{215,151,66}
\newcommand{\lett}[1]{\huge\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=12]
        \duck[longhair=brown!20!black,  
            squareglasses=brown!50!black, body=red, head=yellow] 
    \end{scope}
  \marmot[
    yshift=7cm,xshift=3cm,
    signpost={\lett{H}},
      signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ];
  \bear[
    yshift=7cm,xshift=5cm,
    signpost={\lett{a}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \koala[
    yshift=7cm,xshift=7cm,
    signpost={\lett{p}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \owl[
    yshift=7cm,xshift=9cm,
    signpost={\lett{p}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \mouse[
    yshift=7cm,xshift=11cm,
    signpost={\lett{y}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \begin{scope}[yshift=3cm,xshift=4cm, scale=1.5]
    \duck[ 
      body=yellow!50!brown!40!white,
      crazyhair=gray!50!white,
      eyebrow,
      signpost={\lett{T}},
      signcolour= gray,
      signback=white,
      glasses=brown!70!black,
      ]  
  \end{scope}
  \sloth[
    yshift=3cm,xshift=7cm,
    signpost={\lett{e}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \begin{scope}[yshift=3cm,xshift=8cm, scale=1.5]
    \duck[cap,
      signpost={\lett{X}},
      signcolour= gray,
      signback=white,]
  \end{scope}
  \coati[
    yshift=3cm,xshift=11cm,
    signpost={\lett{m}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \snowman[
    yshift=3cm,xshift=13cm,
    signpost={\lett{a}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
  \penguin[
    yshift=3cm,xshift=15cm,
    signpost={\lett{s}},
    signcolour= gray,
    signback=white
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it because it has marmot, ducks, penguins etc.?

Comment: @Raaja Because I don't know it the sweater is beautiful or not :)

Comment: let's leave it over to the audience then ;)

Comment: A good example why Italy is famous for its fashion industry! Will you present it at the Milan Fashion Week?

Comment: @samcarter For sure, lol!

Comment: @CarLaTeX You can even use your name for the new label: `CarLaTeXile`

Answer (score 7):

Since the purest form of art is ASCII art, the following enters in category 1. But since I'm aware that beauty lies within the eye of the beholder, it also enters in category 2. So in terms of the alphabetic numeration of entry types in `[2]` of the rules, this is a `c`.

## Without avatar

Note that, since this is TeXed ASCII art, it doesn't contain my personal avatar, but there is a bunny on the sweater.

[image]

Because I was asked to, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{ducksay}
% Originally I didn't want to load TikZ, but I'm more familiar with it than with
% picture mode (shame on me), and I was too lazy to align the stuff with skips.
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \DrawASCII { +v }%>>>
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \ #1 }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_ducksay_ligatures_tl
      { \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 } { { ##1 } } }
    \ducksay_replace_verb_newline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \tabularnewline\null }
    \frenchspacing
    \l_ducksay_body_fount_tl
    \begin{tabular} { @{} l @{} }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \end{tabular}
    \group_end:
  }%<<<
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\boxy[2][1]%>>>
  {%
    \scalebox{#1}{\expandafter\usebox\csname#2Box\endcsname}%
  }%<<<

\newsavebox\messageBox
\newsavebox\villageBox
\newsavebox\sweaterBox
\newsavebox\sleighBox
\newsavebox\bunnyBox

\begin{document}
\setbox\messageBox\hbox%>>>
  {%
    \smash
      {%
        \makebox[0pt][c]
          {\ducksay[snowman,arg=box,body=\scriptsize]{Happy TeX-mas}}%
      }%
  }%<<<
\setbox\villageBox\hbox{%>>>
% source (altered): https://www.asciiart.eu/holiday-and-events/christmas/other
\DrawASCII
@ .-.
 ( (                                                       \ /
  '-`                                                     - * -
                                                           / \
                                     |
                                    -+-
            \            o          _|_          \
            ))          }^{        /___\         ))
          .-#-----.     /|\     .---'-'---.    .-#-----.
     ___ /_________\   //|\\   /___________\  /_________\
    /___\ |[] _ []|    //|\\    | A /^\ A |    |[] _ []| _.O,_
....|"#"|.|  |*|  |...///|\\\...|   |"|   |....|  |*|  |..(^)....@%
}%<<<
\setbox\sleighBox\hbox{%>>>
% source (altered): https://www.asciiart.eu/holiday-and-events/christmas/other
\DrawASCII
{           __
          a@@@
   a@a   a@@@@
(__@@@@@@@@@@@__
 (_______\_\_____}%
}%<<<
\setbox\sweaterBox\hbox{%>>>
\DrawASCII
{                     _,,-""""""""""",,_
           ,,,,--==-=;,                ,;=-==--,,,,
       _-"'""         ';,            ,;'         ""'"-_
     ,"                 ",,        ,,"                 ",                       
    /                     ",,    ,,"                     \                    
   /                        ';,,;'                        \                 
  (                           ""                           )              
  |                                                        |
  |                                                        |
  (        |                                      (        |
  |        |                                      |        |
  )        )                                      )        )
  |        |                                      |        |
  (        )                                      (        )
  |        |                                      |        |
  (        (                                      (        (
  |        |                                      |        |
  |        )                                      |        )
  |        )                                      |        |
  |        )                                      |        )
  (        |                                      (        |
  |        |                                      |        |
  (        |                                      (        )
  |        |                                      |        )
  (        |                                      (        |
  |        |                                      |        |
  |________|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"||________|
 / | |  | | \| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | / | |  | | \
|| | |  | | ||_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_||| | |  | | ||
|| | |  | | ||                                  || | |  | | ||
 \_|_|__|_|_/                                    \_|_|__|_|_/}
}%<<<
\setbox\bunnyBox\hbox%>>>
  {%
    \ducksay[bunny,arg=tab,msg-align=c,wd=12]
      {%
        The rabbits and bunnies of the TeX conglomerate wish you a merry
        Christmas!%
      }%
  }%<<<

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\boxy[2]{sweater}};
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-.5cm]
    \node {\boxy{village}};
    \node[rotate=-30] at (-2,2) {\boxy[.65]{sleigh}};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2,-5.2) {\boxy{message}};
  \node at (4,6) {\boxy{bunny}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## With avatar

The following contains my avatar converted to ASCII art (stripped background with Gimp, converted to ASCII). It is created huge and shrunk to 10% to get some detail into it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{ducksay}
% Originally I didn't want to load TikZ, but I'm more familiar with it than with
% picture mode (shame on me), and I was too lazy to align the stuff with skips.
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \DrawASCII { +v }%>>>
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \ #1 }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_ducksay_ligatures_tl
      { \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 } { { ##1 } } }
    \ducksay_replace_verb_newline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \tabularnewline\null }
    \frenchspacing
    \l_ducksay_body_fount_tl
    \begin{tabular} { @{} l @{} }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \end{tabular}
    \group_end:
  }%<<<
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\boxy[2][1]%>>>
  {%
    \scalebox{#1}{\expandafter\usebox\csname#2Box\endcsname}%
  }%<<<

\newsavebox\messageBox
\newsavebox\villageBox
\newsavebox\sweaterBox
\newsavebox\sleighBox
\newsavebox\bunnyBox
\newsavebox\avatarBox

\begin{document}
\setbox\messageBox\hbox%>>>
  {%
    \smash
      {%
        \makebox[0pt][c]
          {\ducksay[snowman,arg=box,body=\scriptsize]{Happy TeX-mas}}%
      }%
  }%<<<
\setbox\villageBox\hbox{%>>>
% source: https://www.asciiart.eu/holiday-and-events/christmas/other
\DrawASCII
@ .-.
 ( (                                                       \ /
  '-`                                                     - * -
                                                           / \
                                     |
                                    -+-
            \            o          _|_          \
            ))          }^{        /___\         ))
          .-#-----.     /|\     .---'-'---.    .-#-----.
     ___ /_________\   //|\\   /___________\  /_________\
    /___\ |[] _ []|    //|\\    | A /^\ A |    |[] _ []| _.O,_
....|"#"|.|  |*|  |...///|\\\...|   |"|   |....|  |*|  |..(^)....@%
}%<<<
\setbox\sleighBox\hbox{%>>>
% source (altered): https://www.asciiart.eu/holiday-and-events/christmas/other
\DrawASCII
{           __
          a@@@
   a@a   a@@@@
(__@@@@@@@@@@@__
 (_______\_\_____}%
}%<<<
\setbox\sweaterBox\hbox{%>>>
\DrawASCII
{                     _,,-""""""""""",,_
           ,,,,--==-=;,                ,;=-==--,,,,
       _-"'""         ';,            ,;'         ""'"-_
     ,"                 ",,        ,,"                 ",                       
    /                     ",,    ,,"                     \                    
   /                        ';,,;'                        \                 
  (                           ""                           )              
  |                                                        |
  |                                                        |
  (        |                                      (        |
  |        |                                      |        |
  )        )                                      )        )
  |        |                                      |        |
  (        )                                      (        )
  |        |                                      |        |
  (        (                                      (        (
  |        |                                      |        |
  |        )                                      |        )
  |        )                                      |        |
  |        )                                      |        )
  (        |                                      (        |
  |        |                                      |        |
  (        |                                      (        )
  |        |                                      |        )
  (        |                                      (        |
  |        |                                      |        |
  |________|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"|"||________|
 / | |  | | \| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | / | |  | | \
|| | |  | | ||_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_||| | |  | | ||
|| | |  | | ||                                  || | |  | | ||
 \_|_|__|_|_/                                    \_|_|__|_|_/}
}%<<<
\setbox\bunnyBox\hbox%>>>
  {%
    \ducksay[bunny,arg=tab,msg-align=c,wd=12]
      {%
        The rabbits and bunnies of the TeX conglomerate wish you a merry
        Christmas!%
      }%
  }%<<<
\setbox\avatarBox\hbox{%>>>
\def\arraystretch{.8}%
\DrawASCII
{                                                                          OI?+==~~~~~IZ   .          O7?~~:~~=+77$$$$77$77$  .
                                                                       .OI+=~~~:~=====7I  .       Z?=~::~=+I$$$$77I777III$,   .
                                                                      ZI+~~~:,:~++?++?Z  . .  +$~,,:~~+I7$Z$7IIIIII???7Z ..
                                                                 .. O7:::~::~~~~++?+?7   . .?~::,:~~?7$$77II7IIIII?I$= .
                                                            ..    .I=,,,:~~~=++=+??IZ.   Z?~::,:~~=7$$$7II77777I?I$
                                                                 =7::,,,:======+??III????:,:,,~=+?7Z$7III7I7I???:
                                                            .   Z?~,,,::~~===++III?+====~:::+=+?7ZZ7IIIIII7I+?$ .      ..
                                                        .   O$7?=~::,,::~~=+=?III+=~=+:~::==??I7Z$7I77IIIII?$.    .
                                                      .  O$?:::~~:,~::=~~~+=+I77?=~+=~:,:~=+7$ZZ77IIIIIII??I
                                                ..    .Z7=:~====:,,:~~=~+~==I77I~~=~:,,~=?I$ZZ$77III7III?II???I77
                                                    .OI+=======~,..:~+++?==?77I+===,,,~~+$ZZ$$$7I??III???I++IIIIII7Z. .
                                 I DD 8~.   . . ..O7+=~===~~~~=~,::~=+?II+?7$I=~+=:,~=+I$ZZZ$77IIIIII?+?I+++++??7$$$77 .
                              . .D87??ZOD   .Z Z+=~:::==~~~~=~=~,,:~~=IIII7$I=~+=:,:=+7ZOZZZ7IIII?????II+==~~===+?I$$77$:
                                I7=~=?I7O   O7+========~~~~~~~~,,,,===777$$$=~==,~=~+7OZZZZ$?IIII??+?I?=~~~~~~~~===I$$?I7?.
                              . 7=:::~+?$   ===~~=+=~~~~~:::~~::,,:==?7$$$I=~==:~~??$OZZZZ$$$7II?++II?~~::~~~~~~===+I77II$Z$
                              . +?III++7ZO87~:~==~:~~:::,:,:~:,::::=+$$7$+~~+~,,~~+ZOZZZZ$$$I7I??II=~~====++++++????II$7?$$$7$= .
                                ++~+$I7$ZZ$+:=++:,::,,:::,:~::,::~~?$$7?=:=+::~+?+7OZZ$$$7I?++????++?????IIIIIIIIIII77$$77$$7I7Z
                                7=:777ZZZZ7===~~:,::,,::::~=:,,,:~?ZZ?~:~?+::~=++7ZOZZ$?=~+?IIIIIII777IIIIIIIIIIIIIII7$$$777$777=  .
                                7::$ZZ$$$$7===~::,::::,::==:,:~=??II???I??=~~=??$OOZI+~?77?=??II7777IIIIIIII?IIIIIII77$77I??7$77$$   .
      . .        .  .      . +7II~=?=?$7$Z7?=~=~:::::~~==~=++=??:~=++==?I?7$?IIIOOI~+$7+=+?I7777777III???????????+?II7$7I+++??7$7$Z  .
         ?=~?I+=.   .   .  ?:::~I=I++?I$ZZ7?==~:::~~:~++++::+?+?I??===:~I7$7Z77O$=+ZI~=+?7$$7$77III??++++++++++++++II77II??++=+I77$~ .     .
        I,,:?IZ7III?+==+?+~==?I?=?$=++777Z$7=~~~~:.,,:~+=,.~+I7ZI7$I??=++$$7$ZO$?OZ?=+I7$$$$$7II?+=~~~~==~~=++++==+?I7I?+?????+?77?IZ
        +,::+I7$ZZ$$$Z77I7II$I~:+?7+I7I7$ZZ$=~~=:.:=~~~:.,~=I$OOI??$$77?+$$$Z$I78ZI?II7$$$$7II?+=::::::~~::~++++~==+I7?=+++?II??77I+?$.
        I:,:=+7ZZZZ$ZZ$$$7$Z~=?++==7777$$ZZZ?=++,,:=~~~,.=++$OO$$ZZZ7$$$$7$7ZZO8OZOZZZ$ZZ$7I+==~~~~:,,~~~:,:=+++:~~?I7+====?III?7$II+I.
        ?,,,~~=?ZZZZZZZ$$7$7$I+~=?7III=?IZZZ$?+:,~~~~=,,~=+I$$$OOZ$$Z$$$777IZZOOZOOOOZOZZI?+~==~,::::::::~~=+++=:==I77=~==+??I77$7?77I~
       .I~~~II=::?$8OOZ$$ZZ$$7I7$7?+=~+I7$ZZ+~,,~::=~:.:~=IZZ+:?IZIZ$I+?77I?OOZZZZZZOZZO$+~~:::::,,,:~~::~=+++==++?I?=~=+=++?I$$$I?II7Z+
          ZII$$7=~~==?7$Z$$ZZZZZI?+===?$Z$$I:~~:~~~~=~=+=?7OO$77$Z?$7=~I$77$7ZZZOZOZOZ$Z$=,,~~~~::,,:~~~~=+++==+??I+=~~=+=++?I$$7??II7$7 .                    .
            Z$$ZZZZZ$$$$$ZZZZZZZ7?===?777Z$+,.,:+=~,,~,:=7ZO$7IIIIII7=?$Z?~?$$$$ZOOZZZ$$7+,,:~==~~::~:~~:++++++??++=::~+?+++I$$$I??III$Z,
      . , I$7?+==~~===I7$$ZZZ$$ZZ$I+?II7$$?:,:~==:.:=+~=?ZO$777I???+:+7ZZI~=ZZ$$ZOOZZ$Z$7I==++++=====~==+???IIII==+=::~=+??+$$$Z??III7$ZO
 .   .?=~~=++?+++???I??I7Z$ZZZ$$$ZZ777$$$ZI+~~=~==~~~?II$$7+?????==+I7$$$+~?$ZZ$ZZOZZZ$7I??++??+,..~~~=+++++?I?++??I=~==+??IZZZ$?I?II7ZZZ~
     7:~::~I7I7$$$ZI????I77$ZZZ$Z$$ZZZZZ$$I~~~=~~+?II?77I=~,..,~=+?$$$Z$7~++OOOZZOOZZ$$I==~~~~=+===?+===~=+??II??+?7=~++???$$ZZ7?I??I7ZZZZ,
    $=~~++++IIII$ZZZ$II??7$$$$$Z$$ZZZZZZ$=~~:~??+=~+??:~:,,,~=+=+??II7$$7IIIZZOOZOOZZ$?+=:~~~~~~==+??++=:~==?II+~+7I+=?I77$ZZZ$II??II7$ZZZO,
    I==~~~~:=+?+=+I7I?++??77$$ZZ7$ZZZZ$$I,:,,+=:+~?~~+,,~?II77$77II7777$$777ZZOOO8OZZI+~,:~~:,,:::~=??==~~~=I7I==?III7II7$ZZZ$I?I???I77ZZZO=
  . .7==+~~~?II+~~:~=+$Z7?I7Z7=+ZZZZ$ZZ$=::,+:,=::,=+~=?+???III$$ZZOOZZZZZ$7$$Z8OOO$I?,:~~:,,.,:~~=+?I=:::~=III++?II7$7$$ZZZZ$I?II??7$7ZZZOO
    . ?=+===+II7ZZZZOZ???+II::?ZZZ$$$$7=:,,=::+==~+:~+=+?7ZZOOOOOOZ$$$ZZ$$$$$$ZOOOOI?=:=~,,,..,::~=+?I+~,:~=I77++?II7$$ZZZZO$I?I?II?7$7ZZZOO   .
      +$$77777$$Z+~OO77I?I?~?$ZOZZZZZO+~~~=~===~+?~=?+?I$ZOZZOZZO7ID8Z$$$$OZ$$$ZOO$?+~=~,,,,.,,::~=??I?~:==+77?+?I7$ZZZZZZOO7I?I???I7$7$$ZOO?
        .  .       OZ$7+=I~?ZOOOZO~   =~:~~:+=..+,:=~=ZZOZZ$ZZ7=8O$DN8O$$Z$$ZOZZO$7?==~:,,,.,.:~=++?+I?~~=+I$7?+I$$ZZZZZOOZZ7IIII??7$$7$$ZOOO
               .. $ZZZ?==7$$Z7        =::,,,~~+I.,+=?$77OZOZ?ZNZ8N8NNN88O$ZOZZZZ7??++=~::,,.:===:=+??7=:~+?7$I??$ZZZOOOOOZ$7IIII??I$$$$$$ZZOO~
      .          OO$$$++I$$Z       . 7,~=::=:+7+~+I?ZZOZIZ8$=IZZO8DD88DOZOZ$OO$Z+==++=~::::,=:::~=+II7=~=?I$7??IZOZZOOO8O$$7I777777$$$$$$ZZOO7
                 ZOZ$$77$ZO      . 7==$$Z+:=+??=?IIO$$7ZZ7O8$I$ZO88OOOZ8O$ZO$ZO$~~~++=~:,,,,~:~~=+?II$===?7$I?I$ZZZOO88OOZ$7$$$77$$$$$$$$ZZZOZ~
                 ZZZZZ$ZZ        Z+77?$=+$~~II=:I7$8O8D8I+ZO    O8O$Z8~=7O7$$$ZI=:~+==~,::~=::~=++?777=++7$Z77$OOZZO888OOZZ$$$$$$$$$$$$ZZZ$ZO8+
             .    7$ZZ7.    ..  ZZ77I$$IIZ~:I$++$O? DDO:~I7    .OZ$7Z$8OZZ$Z$Z$?:,=+=~::~:::~===??I$7I??I$$$ZOOZZZZO8888OOOZZZZZZZ$$ZZZZZZ$ZOO8. .
              .        .     .  II7$II$7ZI,:7OII8    .    :  IOZ$7Z~.=7Z$$$77ZZ+~:====~::::~~==+II7$$777$ZZZOZZZOOZO88888OOOOOZZZZZZZZZZZ$$ZOO8:
                                7ZZ7$ZOZ$,,=$77Z~           Z$ZO7I7OOI$$Z777ZOZI~~=+=~~::~~~==?I7$$Z$7$$ZZZZZ$$ZZZOO88888888OOOOOOOZZZZZZ$ZZOO8:
                                :?I7ZZI+::=?7ZOO        ..  $$ZZ7:,+IO$$$I7$OOO7::====~=~~==+?I7$ZZ$$ZZZZ$I?II77ZZOO888OOO888888OOOZZOZZ$ZZZOO8=
                              . ~=+=:::~=I$ZO$Z+   .   .   OZOOZ887IZOZZ7$$O~ :$~:==+===~==+I7$$ZZZZ$$77I+==+?I7ZZOO888OOOOOZO8888OOOOZZZZZZOO8:
                               .?$7I??+I$OZ$7Z?           ~Z$Z7$8ZZZ7$777Z8$ .. ?=+++==+=+?I$$ZZZ$7??I??++++~=?IZZOO88OOOOOZOOOZZO88OOOZZZZZOO8: .
                              .   ~??I$Z?IIIZ8            $$Z$88OOZOOI7I78=.    $+++==+==?I7$Z$7++++=+===~=+~++?$ZOO8OOOOOZZOOZ$ZOOOOOOOZZZOO88   .
                                   ?8OZ88ZOOO      .    .ZZ$Z88D88OZ7I7$O     . 7+:~+?+??II??++====~~~~~=~~==??I$ZOO8OOOOOOOOZ$$OOZZOOOOOOOOO8? ..
                                 . .I+ZO=I+I=        .,OZ$7Z87O$ZOZIIIZ=       $=++==~I??+~~++==::~:,::~~~~=+I77ZZOO8OO8OOOOZZZOOZ$ZOOOOOOOO88$.      ...
                                    I+?7 7:=Z ..   . 77$7O~. +$ZZ$IIIZ .  . 7?=~~:~~~~==~:==~~~~,,::~::~~~==?I7$ZZO88OOOOOO8OZOOZZZOOZZZZOOOO8=    ~.  +~ .
                                     $=7~~?:7:     .. +=~   Z$ZO$7I7O,     ==~~::::~===~~~==::,.::,:~~:~~===I7$$ZOO888OOOO88ZZZOOOOOZZZZZOOO88?  $7     I.
                                      +?Z .?IO  .   . .   .ZZZZ$77?O.  .  7=~~~~======~~~~~~:,,..,::::~~~+++7$$$ZOO888888OOZZOOOZZZOZZZOOOO88O$  ?$7 +~=7 :
                                      $?7  ??Z      . .  ~$$7?II7I7    . ?::,:~~:::~===~=~~~:,,,,,,~~====+?I$ZZ$ZOO888888OOOOOOZZOOOZZOOOOOOOOO,.+$I7I7?7??,
                                        7 . $$?      ..$?+I7OO$I$O,     7~~~~~:::~=~~~~====~:,,,:::~~===+I7$ZZ$ZOO8DD888888OOOOOOOOZZOOOZOOOOZO= :7II?77II7= . .
                                     .              7??I7ZO8IIIZ?.  .  I~,,,:,.,=~~:,:===~~::,::~==?+++?I$ZZZ$ZZOO8D8D88D888OOOOOOZOOOZZZOOOOOOO  ~III777II7=?:=
                                       .. .  .             .:         I=:,,,,,:~~::::~=+===~~~=+???III7$ZZOOZZZOO888888888DD88OOOOOOOOZZOOZZZZOO  .7I7777I77II:+
                                     .         .    .      . .        +~:,,::==~::::~~+=:==~=+I7$$ZZZZOOZOOZZOOO8DD8D88888888888888OOZZOOZZZZZZO~~=7777$7II77I7+
                                         .     .                ...  $=:.,:,==~:,,:~~===:+==?7$ZZZZZOOOOOOOOOOOODDDDDDD888888888888OZZZZZ$$$ZZZO$$777$$$777777=
                                     .      .             .          I~:,,:==~~~~:~~==+~~+=+I$ZZ$ZZZOOOOOOOOOOOO888888888DDDD8888OOZOOZZZ$$ZZZOOOZ$$$$$77$$$$=.
                                          .. ?$$$$$777777777777$77777?=::,~=====:~=+++===~~?$ZZ$$ZZOOOOOOOOOOO8D8DDDDDDDDDDD8888OOOOOOZZ$$ZZZOOOOZ$7=?$$$I$7~,
                                       Z$7I????+++++++???????????????+=~=+?+====++++++=+++I7ZZ77ZZZOOOZOOOZO88DD888DD8DDD88888OOOOOOOZZ$ZZZZOOOOOOZ~,~$Z7I$$$+,
                  .          . .  ZI?++++==~~~~~~~~========++??I?????+==~:::~==+=+++==++~=I$Z77$ZZOOOZZOOOO8DDDDDDDDDDDDDD8888OOOOOZZZZZZZZZOOZOOOO7?+I7IZZZ,
                        .    ?7?++===~=~~~~~~~::~~~~~~~~=+??++++?I?+=~::,,,~====+++++++++I$$77$$ZOOOOOZOODDD88DDDDDDDDDDDD88888OOOZZZOOZOOOOZZZOOOOZI+?++7$:
                  .   .  7??=~~~~~~::~~~~~~~~~:::::~~~===~~~===+?+==~.,::==~~===+??++++~=7$77$$ZOOOOOZO+8DDD88DDDD8DDDDDDD88OOOOZZOOOOOOOOOZZZZZOOOOO77ZZZ7:
                      7+~~+=~:::,::::,,,:~~~===~~~~~~~~~:~~~~==?~::~::~~~~~~=+++?II???=+I$7I$$ZZOOOO~  ?88DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD888OOOOOOOOOOOOZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOOO~~,
               .  .  I:~+~~~:,:~::::,:,,:~~~~~~===+++=~~~=~~+++=.,:~~~::::~~+???I7I?I?=I$I77$ZZZO8OI .. :DDD8DDDDDDDDDDD8OOO8OOOOOZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOO7?,, .
             .  . .7?:==~~::,,,,.,:,,::~=~::::::~~~~~~===~~==::~,:~~~~:::~==+?I77IIIII7$$7$$ZZZOOOO. . . DDDDDDDDDDDDD888888OOZZZZZOZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOO?=:
              .    =~==~~:,,,,..,,,:::~~~:::::::~~~~~~~~:=+=:,:~~~=~:~====+?I77$7IIIII$$$$ZZZOOOOZO~,  :8DDDDDDDDDDDD88888OOZZZZZOOZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOZ. .
                 ~I~==~:,:,,,,.,,::~:::::::~~~~~===~~~::~+=:::~~~~~~==+?I7$7ZZZZ???I7$Z$ZZZZOOOOZO888O888DDDDDDDDDDD888OOZZZZOOOOOZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOOO? .
                 ?~~+==~~,:,,,,::::,,:::~~~======++=~~~===::~~:~==++?I777$$$Z$I+?I?I$ZZZZ$$$OOOZO88888888DDDDDD8D88D8OOZZOZZOZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOOO,       .
              . I+:=++=~~:,,,:::::,,,:=~~=++++++=~::~~=++~==~:~=+?I?+?+??II7I?++?+?$ZZ$7$$ZZOOZO888888888888DDDDDDD8OZZZZZZOZZZZZZZZZZOOOOZZOOOOOOOO+  ..
             . .$+~??++=~~~~~======~~===+++??++=::::::=====~~=++++++++=++I7II?===+IZZZ$77$ZZOZO8888888888DDDDDDDD88ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOZZZOOO88OOO:,  ,   .
            . . ?I??++??+=+++++++?+++???II??~===~~~:~=+==~~=+++?++==~=+?III?+=~~?I$Z$Z7I7ZZOZ88D8DDD88DDDDDDDD88OOZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOZZZZZZO888OOOO:,
                 Z7?==???+??????II7777III??=~~~~~~~++=~:~~=+===+~~~===++?II?+=~+7$ZZZ$ZZZOOO8D88DDDD888DDDDN8OOZZZZZZZZZ$ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOO8888ZZOO
              .    I=:~~==+++===?I7777I?++==~~==::~+=~+++=~~~~~==~~++??II++==++IZZZZZO8OOOO8D88888DD88DDD8OOOZZ$$777II777$$$ZZZZZZZOZZZOOO88888OOOO
                   =$?::~~==~~:~:~~=+?I????+==~:~=+=+++=~~::~~::===?????+++=?I7$ZOOOOOOOO888D8DDDDDDDDD8OOZ$7777?++=+???I77$$$ZZZZZOZZOO888888OZOOO
                 .  :OI?+~~=~~:,:=I7$$$$$777??+=??+++=:~:::~~~~=+++?I??+==+I$$ZZOOOOOOOOO8DDD8DDDDDDDDOZZ777+==~~~~:~+++????7$ZZZZZZZOO888OO88OOO88D
                     .Z$7??++==+IIII?+~~=7ZOZZZ7??+~~~::,~~~====++???+++?I$ZZZOOOOOOOOOOO888DDDDDDD88O$7I+++====~~~~~~===+??I7$ZZZZOOO888O88OOOO888DN.  .
                       ZOO$$7777777?+=~~~~~=+?I?==~~~~===~~=??+????=+?I7$ZOZZOOOOZZOOOZO8DDDDDDDDNDOZ7?++======~~~~~~~===++?II7$ZZZOOOO88O88OOO888O888  .  . .
                   .   . OOO8OOOZZ$I?++++==+??+=::::~~~==++++++?I777$$ZZOZZZOO8OOOOOOOO8888888DDDDO7I?+++===~~~~~~=~~=====++?I77ZZZOOO8OOOOOO8888OO88888
                            OO88OOOZ$$77I7I?=~::::~~~~=+++++??III77ZOOZOZZOO8OOZOO8OOO88888888888Z7?++=++====~~:~~~===~==+++?II7$ZZOOO8OOOOO8D88OOOOO8888 .
                              ZOOO8OOOZ$7?+~:~~~~~~~~===++?I777$$ZZ$7$ZZZOOOOOOO88OOO88888888888$I+===++==~~~~~~========++++?I77$ZZOO8OOOOO88888888888888
                           .    +ZOOOZ7I?=~~:~==~==~+?=++77$77$$7II7ZZZOOOOO8888OO888888888888OZ+++++++=========~~~===+??++???II7$ZO88OOO88D8888888888888?.
                             ...  :Z$I+++~:~~~==~~==???7I7I7$7I?I7$ZZZOO8888OOOO8DDD888888888O$?+++==+======~:~~~~~===+++???IIII$ZOO8O88888888888888D8888Z.
                                  $?+=======+=~~::~+??7?=I$$77I$ZZZZO888OOOOO88DNDDDDDD8DD88O7I+++====+===~:~~~:~~~==++++??I?III$OOOOO8D88888888OO88D888O8=$
                        .     .+ I+~~====++=~~===+?7I?++I$$$ZZZZOO8888OOO888DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDI?+====+==~====~~~~~~=~==++???II??I7ZOOO888888888888888888OOO87
                             .:7?+====+++==~=+++?III+?I7$ZZO8888888OO8888DDD888DDDDDDDDDDDDZ?+=~===+==~~=~~=~~~======++??III??7$OOO888888888OOO8888888O88Z?
                             7II~~~~~=====~~+++?II??I7$ZZ8DD88888O88DD888D88888DDDDDDDDDD8ZI==~===~===~~~======~=~==++??II???I$ZOO888888888O8888888O88888I . .
                          :7I+++=~~~=~~~~=====+??I7$$$O8D8OOOOOOOOO8888OOO8O88888888DDD8D$??==++=~~~=+=~~~~~~===~~=++??II??+I$ZOO8888888OO88D8D88OO88O8O8 .
                    = 7?++I?+++=~~~~==~~=~:~====?7$ZOO888~,        =7~ . OOOOOOO8O88888D8I?+=+===~~~~====~~~~=====++?????++?$ZOO888888888DDDD8888888O8O8?
                .  I=~::=I?++=~~======~~=~~~==+++I$O88?~ .        .         .,~+ZOOOOO8O7+++++=~~~~:~~=++~~~=====++????+?+?IZOOO888888DD8DDD8888888O8O8.  .  .
                  I+=~~=??++=======~~=~~~~~~===+I$ZZZ=   .   .        .       .   $ +OZ7?+++=+~~~~~:~~=+=~~~====++????++??I$OO88DDDDDDDDDDDD8888888OOO....  .
                I?+~+=+??++=~===~~:==~~::+===?I??$O. :              .     .     .  . ZI?+~=+=~~~~==~~~+=~~====++?????+???I$O888888DDDDDDNDDDDD8888OO8      . .
          .. I??=++++??+==~~==~~=:~===::~=+=??++I$O .                          .   +.=?=~=====~~~~~==+======++++?II+++?IIZO888DD8DD8DDNNNDDD88888OOO?
       .....?=~++??I?+===~~=~=~~~~==~==:==+==+++$OO                               = 7I+~=+====~:~~=+++====+++????????I7$Z8888D8888ODNNNDDND8888OOO8$.
         ,.I~~++?I7?++::~==~==:~,~=~==~:=~=++==+ZO$.                            .,.7??+~==~~=========+++++++?????+??I7ZO8888DD888O8MNDND8888888888O
         .I???III7I+~~==~++~===+:~=~====+~==?+?IOO                                7+++=~+===~~=====+=+++???????+??I7$ZO88O8D88D8O8NNNNNNDOO888OOO8 .
      . 77$7$77$I?+~,~===II++=+~~~=+???+=:~=7$$ZO?   .   .                      ,.I==~~=++++++=======+++????????I77ZOOOO8D8O8888DNNNNNDDD88O8OOO?
       I?OZZZZ$7===???~~+$$7++=:=~=I$$??=:~+7ZO8I                               7I+~~~~==+++=====~=+++????????I7$ZO8888DDZZOOOO8NNNDNDDD888888OO
      +I8OO$ :I+~==?==?7ZOO7?+=~~=?O8OI?=~==$OOO     .              . .  ,$I7I77?==~::=+=+=======+++++???I?I7$ZOOOOO88OZ$ZOOOODNNNDDND8O8O88OOO7.
     .$8O   :7++++?++?7O8$7????+==IOOZ$?~~~~IOI                    .   ,=$77+?77+~~::~=====+=++===+?????I77$ZZOOOO88Z7$$$ZOO8DNNNDDDD8888O88OOI
   . ?8O   .7I+~~~~?I$88Z77++==+?+7O$7$I++++ZO:~                ..    +?$??+I77I=~~~~~=========+++?????I7$$ZOOOO88O77I7$ZOOO8NNDNNDD88888OOOO8   .
    ..8.    I+=~===7ZO=?$7I+++++77O?7$7?=++?ZO                .   .I$$I?+++?7$7?=~:::~=======++++?????I7$ZOOZOO8Z7??I77$ZO8ODNND8DD88O888OO888?
  .  .O~  .+++==++?OOZ .:7?~~:~=7Z8 . $+==~+Z                  ,$7777I??+?II77I+==~::~=+=======+??IIII7$$ZZZO88O??II7$$ZOOO8NDDD88888O88OO88O8$ .
     ::.   I=====I7OZ:  77=~=~=?$OO...7+=~~=Z          .  . .$$7++?=++==?I??7I?+==~~~=+====+===+?II777$ZZ$ZZO8$?IIII7$ZO8O8NDDD88D88OO88OO8OO888 .
     =    7?====?$ZZ     I====+IOO    $?===+ZO     .        $77?~~~?I7I??++=$I++=~~~~==+++===+???I77$$Z$$$ZZ8ZI?777$$ZO8O8DNDD8O8DD8OO8OO88OO87
         7?====+$OO.   =7+==~=+7      $+=~=+ZO    .    ..,.7+=~7==II??+??+=+$?+=~=====+??+==+???7777$Z$7IZZO$??7$77ZOOOOONNDD8O8D88OO8OOO8OO8$   .
        ~7I+++??OZ$   77I+++=??$$     $I????ZO    . . . :I=~=I7III7?++~~~+=+$I++===++++??++++?II777$ZO7I7ZO8II$Z77ZOOOOO8NDD888DD88O8DOOO8OO8    .
      ..,I????+?OZ    77?+++?I7Z$     $I7,,?Z+ ...     .~=+I7$Z$7I?+?7?+=+I7Z$I?=+++++?++?????I7777ZOO$$Z8OZI$ZZ$ZZ8OO8DDND8O88D8888D8OO8OOO8 .
        .7I?+I77OO .  :7?++==?$O       77,.+O.       .:I:?7OD888+~:==?7?+77I$O$$????????++??+++I$77ZOZZO8O$7ZOZZO88OO8D8DD8O8DD8888D88OO8OOOO
        .77+:+ZZ?.  , 7II:,~7?$O  .     ,..I          ??ZDDDOZ$?~=++?I7I7II$?7OZZZ$$$77I7I?++++IZ$$OOOOOZ$$ZOZZOOOO8DD88D8OO8888D88D88OO8OOO8
        .?$++7OO    .,?7$,,+77O~     .  .,,7 +    .   OD8   ,I?+?I7O8Z$$I?+=7??$ZZZZ$$I??II7III7Z$ZOOOOZZOOOOOOO8DDD88888888888888888888OOOOZ
      . ..7=?=O.  .  :++?:,II,           :.7   .       .  . ?+?IO8D8OZO7+:++77II7ZZ$II?+==++$$ZZZ$$OOOZOOOO88DDDDDDDDD88OOOO8888OOOOOOOOOOO87    .
         =$+7O+    .    .:~7       .     ?=  .           ..7?$O8O.. ,II==++I$77777+ZZ$7I??II$$$$$$ZOZZOOODDDDDDDDDD8888888OO888OOOOOOOOOOO88
         .7?7$, .        :+. ...       ...7  .        .  .:~,?$: ,:.+~+++IZO88O8+OO~IOZZZ$$$ZZZZZOOOZO8888888888888OOOOOOOO88OOZZZOOOOOOOOO7
           7~O  .        +7: .       .     .              ,.. .    I7?7$O888.:..7.= .~?OOOOOOOOOO8888  ?8OOO88OO8888OOOOOO88OOOOZZZZZZOOO8
       .  +$OO           I                                         I?+OO:                     :: .   .?8OOOO8888888OOOOOO88O88OZOOZ$ZOOO
         .~~?            I.         .    .                          ~=  .                      .      8OOOOO8888DD8OOO8OO8O8OOZZOOOZZZ
         ,  ..           ::              ,                           .                               :OZZ88?:88888OOOOOOO,? OZOOOOOZO  .
        ..      .                                                                                  ..8ZO8$  .  ?8OOOOOO~  ,~OOOOO88     .
                  .                                                                                 8OO8D.     $8OO888D .  ?OOOO
                  ,                                                                              . 8.  :.    .  OO8DDD      ZZO
                  .                                                                                ..   ...   . 888D?   . . O~
                  .                     ,                                                .           .    .   . 888.        ?  .    .
                              ,                                                                            :. .          , ,}%
}%<<<

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\boxy[2]{sweater}};
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-.5cm]
    \node {\boxy{village}};
    \node[rotate=-30] at (-2,2) {\boxy[.65]{sleigh}};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2,-5.2) {\boxy{message}};
  \node at (4,6) {\boxy{bunny}};
  \node at (-5,7) {\boxy[.1]{avatar}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will David still get the beer if your sweater wins?

Comment: @samcarter yes, why not? So new rules: If either my beautiful sweater wins, or David's first answer, I'll buy him a beer.

Comment: Good to hear!!!

Comment: @samcarter I am happy to see that you are looking after my interests!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just want to make sure that with the handicap of your home country you'll get some real "Bier" :)

Comment: @skillmon could you also show us how you `TeXified` this? Simply, beautiful!

Answer (score 5):

I felt like doing another entry, so here's one for the ugly sweater category (A). It's based on a Christmas tree I created earlier this month, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/465984#465984). It has tinsel, baubles, flashing fairy lights, and a matching hat. :)

[image: Christmas Tree Sweater]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a2paper,portrait]{article}
%\documentclass[export]{standalone}
% All design and code created by Ulysses. Please credit me if you use a significant portion of this anywhere.

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,shapes,fadings}
\usepackage{times}

% Fairy light
\tikzfading[name=littleglow,inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bigglow,inner color=transparent!30,outer color=transparent!100]
\newcommand{\light}[1]{
    \fill[fill=white,path fading=littleglow] (#1) circle (0.2cm);
    \fill[fill=white,path fading=bigglow] (#1) circle (0.7cm);
}

\newcommand{\jumper}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Person
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!20!white!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-6,13) -- (-2.5,13) -- (-2.5,16) -- (2.5,16) -- (2.5,13) -- (6,13) -- (6,5) -- (-6,5) -- (-6,13);
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!20!white!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (0,19.5) ellipse (4.5cm and 5.5cm);

    % Jumper
    \filldraw[fill=green!40!black!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-5,13) arc (180:360:5cm and 3cm) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(10,-17) -- ++(-4,-2) -- ++(-6,10.2) -- ++(0,-17.2) -- ++(-20,0) -- ++(0,17.2) -- ++(-6,-10.2) -- ++(-4,2) -- ++(10,17) -- ++(5,0);
    \filldraw[fill=green!30!black!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-5,13) arc (180:360:5cm and 3cm) -- ++(1,0) arc (180:360:-6cm and 4cm) -- ++(1,0);
    \filldraw[fill=green!30!black!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (20,-4) -- ++(-4,-2) -- ++(-0.5068,0.862) -- ++(4,2) -- ++(0.5068,-0.862);
    \filldraw[fill=green!30!black!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (-20,-4) -- ++(4,-2) -- ++(0.5068,0.862) -- ++(-4,2) -- ++(-0.5068,-0.862);

    % Hat
    \filldraw[fill=green!40!black!,draw=black,line width=3pt] (-5,21) -- ++(5,12) -- ++(5,-12) -- ++(-10,0);
    \draw[draw=black,line width=3pt,double distance=7mm, double=yellow!80!black!,cap=round,dash pattern=on 1mm off 6mm] (-5,21) -- ++(10,0);

    % Star
    \filldraw (0,33) node[fill=yellow!90!black!,draw=black,line width=3pt,star,star points=4,star point ratio=4,scale=4] {};
    \filldraw (0,33) node[fill=yellow!90!black!,draw=black,line width=3pt,star,star points=4,star point ratio=4,scale=4,rotate=45] {};

    % Tinsel
    \draw[draw=black,line width=3pt,double distance=7mm, double=yellow!80!black!,cap=round,dash pattern=on 1mm off 6mm] (10,13) .. controls ++(-1,-4) and ++(4,-2) .. (-10,3);
    \draw[draw=black,line width=3pt,double distance=7mm, double=yellow!80!black!,cap=round,dash pattern=on 1mm off 6mm] (10,3) .. controls ++(-1,-4) and ++(4,-2) .. (-10,-5);
    \draw[draw=black,line width=3pt,double distance=7mm, double=yellow!80!black!,cap=round,dash pattern=on 1mm off 6mm] (10,-5) .. controls ++(-1,-3) and ++(5,-1.5) .. (-10.5,-11.7);

    % Baubles
    \shadedraw[ball color=red,draw=black,line width=3pt] (-6.5,8) circle (1.5cm);
    \shadedraw[ball color=blue,draw=black,line width=3pt] (7,5) circle (1.5cm);
    \shadedraw[ball color=green,draw=black,line width=3pt] (-4,-1) circle (1.5cm);
    \shadedraw[ball color=red,draw=black,line width=3pt] (3.5,-5.7) circle (1.5cm);
    \shadedraw[ball color=blue,draw=black,line width=3pt] (-7,-8.5) circle (1.5cm);
    \shadedraw[ball color=green,draw=black,line width=3pt] (7.5,-10.5) circle (1.5cm);

    % Lights set 1
    \begin{scope}[opacity=#1]
    \light{-3,23.5} \light{1,28} % Hat
    \light{-18,-2.5} \light{-11,5} \light{-8,12} \light{-3,7} % Row1
    \light{9,9} \light{16,1} \light{6,2} \light{0,3} \light{-8,-3} % Row2
    \light{7,-4} \light{1,-8} \light{-4,-7} % Row3
    \light{4.5,-11} % Row4
    \end{scope}

    % Lights set 2
    \begin{scope}[opacity=#2]
    \light{-1.5,27} \light{2.5,23} % Hat
    \light{-15,-2} \light{-11.3,9} \light{0,8} \light{7,12} % Row1
    \light{12,7} \light{16,-3.5} \light{4,5} \light{-1,-1.5} \light{-8.5,1} % Row2
    \light{9,-1} \light{-1.5,-8} \light{-9,-7} % Row3
    \light{2,-11.5} % Row4
    \end{scope}

    % Text
    \draw (0,-12.6) node {\Large Design and code created by Ulysses.};

    % Guide lines
    %\draw[step=1cm,lightgray,very thin] (-20,-14) grid (20,14);
    %\draw[step=5cm,cyan,very thin] (-20,-14) grid (20,14);
    %\draw[step=10cm,red,very thin] (-20,-14) grid (20,14);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,scale=1]{2}
    \jumper{1}{0}
\newframe
    \jumper{0}{1}
\end{animateinline}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, a Christmas Tree, ahhm, Christmas Person :)

Comment: In case you need little hooks to fix your baubles to the tree, see https://github.com/samcarter/Extravanganza2018/blob/master/samcarter/mouse/baubles/bauble_owl.tex#L43 and the line after it.

Comment: @samcarter chritmas trees are the [one thing I can do in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/79151#79151)  (although the syntax always seemed a bit weird compared to picture mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no wonder you have a gold tikz badge :)

Comment: @Ulysses Super!

Comment: Thanks, guys! Glad you liked it. :)