# A question about ducks and other animals

Tags: discussion, users, ducks

I'm just out of curiosity. Why people here (TeX.SX users) love ducks so much? What's wrong with other animals, like dogs, cats, birds, fishes, geese, swans, marmots, penguins, or much more other animals? They are all very friendly and lovely!

[image]

<sup>I just make this picture myself after spending an hour learning how to use the [Ti*k*Zlings](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings?lang=en) and the [Ti*k*Zpeople](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople) package! :))</sup>

Minimal working example, as usual:

```
\documentclass[margin = 2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzlings, tikzpeople}
\tikzset{every node/.style = {align = center}} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\bear[
    3D,
    scale = 2,
    sign post = {\large\color{blue}Hello guys!\\\color{brown!50!black}It's very nice\\\color{brown!50!black}to meet you!},
    speech = {Hey, why am I\\not in the list?},
    sign colour = brown!50!black,
    sign back = yellow!30
]
\node[name = me, person, minimum size = 3cm] at (-10,2) {Me};
\node[
    ellipse callout, 
    fill = black!15,
    yshift = 2cm,
    xshift = -6.5cm,
    callout absolute pointer = {(me.mouth)}
] {Oh, I'm sorry,\\that's my mistake!};
\node[name = bearx] at (-1.5,2) {};
\node[
    ellipse callout, 
    fill = black!15,
    yshift = 1cm,
    xshift = -3cm,
    callout absolute pointer = {(bearx)}
] {I'm so lovely,\\you see.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>PS1 -- I'm sorry, bears :))</sup>

<sup>PS2 -- I recommend @samcarter to make a little change in the Ti*k*Zlings package, so that the size of the board and the speech change automatically depending on the text written on it.</sup>

Comment: Very important question :) About the automatic size change -- I once considered it (and there is even some code written by @loopofpsace) but I think that without it the user has more possibilities. If I would automatically scale things, there is not much the user can change. Without it he/she/it can choose a font size they like, put their text into a scalebox etc. If you want automatic resizing of the speech bubbles, I highly recommend the tikz shapes library, this is also what I used for https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48214260#48214260

Comment: @samcarter making the auto sizing optional wouldn't be too hard, would it?

Comment: @Skillmon Maybe, I'll put it on the ever growing to-do-list :)

Comment: Ducks are the most-loved animals because marmots are beings. ;-)

Comment: @marmot :)) Yes but... what do you mean? I'm confused.

Comment: Marmots cannot be the most-loved animals because we are no animals. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Oh! I got it! ;-)

Comment: Related: [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/168244)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We love any animal, see ["The duck pond": showcase of TikZ-drawn animals/ducks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387047/the-duck-pond-showcase-of-tikz-drawn-animals-ducks?noredirect=1&lq=1)!

But some of them have a special meaning here.

[Duane Bibby's lion](https://ctan.org/lion) is the "trademark" of TeX, there are also Meta the lioness and the Hummingbird logo of LaTeX(3) project, for more info see [LaTeX mascots/associated animals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419984/latex-mascots-associated-animals) and [Why does TeX have a lion as mascot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49087/why-does-tex-have-a-lion-as-mascot).

[Marmots](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8006/preparing-for-groundhog-day) are the favorites of our TikZ expert [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot).

Bär (a teddy bear) is a very valuable member of [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s team.

[Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) is a rabbit, and he likes rabbits, especially with pepper cream sauce :) And his avatar is kind of a rabbit.

Ducks, in particular, and birds, in general, are [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda)'s favorites. He is the author of the the tool [`arara`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara) ("arara" means "macaw", which is a parrot, btw).

He started loving ducks when he made friends with a hearing-impaired girl. To impress her, he mentioned that he studied
ASL (American Sign Language), even if he remembered only: "I love you" and "duck".
Since saying “I love you” to a just-met girl was not very appropriate, he chose “I love ducks”. The girl, of course, started laughing, and since then the duck mania has become to spread all over the world.

You can find the complete story at Section 2 "Origin and evolution of the duck mania" [here](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf). The article is by Herr Professor Paulinho van Duck, of course! He writes the [DuckBoat columns on the TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listauthor.html#Maggi,Carla).

Our moderator [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) is a duck as well.

However, as a proof that we are not biased against other animals, you can see [this video](https://vimeo.com/305374856).

We love donkeys, too: [I need a TeX-donkey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312199/i-need-a-tex-donkey)

P.S. = there are also users who think all this is insane.
Nevertheless, Johannes_B is Señor Pingüino (mister penguin).

Comment: Please tell me  if I forgot something (no, David, I don't mean Chinese duck).

Comment: Professor Paulinho van Duck forgot a "h" in "text dept" in the linked article…

Comment: @TeXnician Ops!

Comment: Oh, thank you! I don't know about the story of Paulo Cereda :)) No matter the story on chat is true or not, this is really the reason why ducks have been so popular so far.

Comment: @Skillmon Added!

Comment: @JouleV You're welcome! Of course, this is the reason.

Comment: You forgot Joseph Wright (our mod) who is a duck as well.

Comment: @yo' Added! Thanks!

Comment: Is this community going insane?

Comment: @Johannes_B Going? We're well past that point I think.

Comment: @Johannes_B Added!

Comment: I just had to ask. After all, i am Señor Pingüino.

Comment: @Johannes_B Added :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX You forgot the Ulrike Fischer's donkeys: [I need a TeX-donkey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312199/14500)... ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Added! :):):)

Answer (score 12):

Dogs and cats don't taste so nice, but Duck is very versatile. Roast Duck, Crispy Duck Pancakes, Duck burgers, ....

Comment: Haha... you made my day :))) RIP those ducks who are in those food :(((

Comment: Actually I really like duck meat or goose meat. But I also like dog meat too (although it is weird and crazy to most of you, but... I'm from Vietnam, and dog meat is a kind of Vietnamese traditional food) :))

Comment: @JouleV one doesn't eat dogs, those are hunting companions. You wouldn't eat your cousin, would you?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes. In many countries, dogs go hunting with people. But in Vietnam and some southeast (I don't mean SE) asian countries, dogs become a guard of houses, or a pretty pet, instead. ;-) Hunting dogs are rare here, I just know about them by watching some movies :))

Comment: @JouleV one doesn't eat ones guard, too!

Comment: @JouleV -- it's probably apocryphal, but i've heard there may be some relevance in the name of the dog breed "chow".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Excellent answer. ahahahahah

Comment: Having eaten dog meat other dogs come to me and bark due to my body odor.